# Compare rows across 2 columns and count value once if it appears twice all within a date range

Tags: excel, excel-2007

hope someone can help on this problem I've hit a brick wall with.

I'm creating a quarterly report, so I need to firstly check that the formula looks at the correct date range. I have been using the following so far:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,">="&B$5,$A:$A,"<="&B$6,$D:$D, "YES")
```

This has been working great, but now I need to compare 2 columns within the date range and only count 1 of the `YES`'s if it appears in both rows.

Not sure if that makes complete sense, so here's an example.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD7hq.jpg)

In the above, I would need to look at the date range 03/02/16 to 06/02/16, compare column 1 and column 2 and only count the `YES` once if it appears in both columns. So in the above, the value would return 4.

And I'm using Excel 2007.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: I'm a little confused. Wouldn't the answer be 2 in your example? Both columns have `YES` only twice between the date range you gave.

Comment: Hi Brian, apologies for the confusion, I am counting the instances on the dates 03/02/16 and 06/02/16 as well as the instances between those two dates, I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dates are in B5 and B6 and the columns to check for yes are C and D:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9<=$B$6)*(A2:A9>=$B$5)*(( D2:D9="YES")+(C2:C9="YES")>0))
```

Comment: Hi Abe, Thanks so much for your reply, it worked perfectly, cheers!

Comment: Abe I was thinking of posting an answer to this but it would be very similar to yours. The only thing when I tested yours was that the '+' in your formula seems to get parsed before the '>' so I believe it's possible to get a wrong answer. It seemed bad manners to just edit yours without permission though. My version would have ended in SIGN((B2:B9="YES")+(C2:C9="YES"))